# How do I maintain watch over multiple background processes and respond according to their return code?

Tags: bash, background-process

In bash, I'm trying to maintain a certain # of processes for downloading files. Basically, I have a list of files from one of two sources. So my script will do the following:

- Read which list is being processed
- Pull the full URL to be fetched
- Extract the actual file name since the URLs are long and ugly and frequently cause files to be misnamed. Each list has it's own position for the filename in the URL so the list name is checked and the position of the filename in the URL is determined from the source file name.
- Begin downloading the file IF the number of active downloads is less than 10
- if Active Downloads = 10 then wait until one of them exits
- on RC of 0 begin downloading the next file in the list.
- on a Non-Zero RC, report the bad RC from wget and abort the script, leaving any currently running wget instances running
- When the list is empty, either because it had less than 10 to start, or all files are being or have been pulled, wait for remaining wget instances to finish cleanly, then exit script cleanly

My problem is that despite wrapping wget in a function and calling that function with &, the wget doesn't go into the background. It pauses the whole script until it finishes. This is not good because some of the URLS are time encoded and if I don't download them within a certain amount of minutes the web server throw errors instead of the files I want. So waiting for each file to finish isn't going to work if I'm pulling 30+ files (not uncommon).

Here's the script. Any help is GREATLY appreciated! Ignore the doDEBUG stuff. That's just troubleshooting I tried that revealed WHAT the problem is but not WHY.

```
#!/bin/bash
# when script is confirmed as working ok. set DEBUG to 0
#set -x # should not be necessary!

DEBUG=1
SET_X=0

doDEBUG() {
    [ $DEBUG -eq 0 ] && return
    if [ $SET_X -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo -n "";
        set -x
        SET_X=1;
    fi
    read -p "Press <ENTER> to Continue..."
}


grabFN() {
    echo `echo $1 | cut -f $FLD -d / | cut -f 1 -d \?`
}

enqueue() { 
    URL=$1 FN=$(grabFN $1)
#   Fetch Limit of 10 processes at once
    doDEBUG
    wget $URL -O $FN -o log.$FN
    doDEBUG
    [ -n $? ] && echo $URL >> $INFILE
}

fetchURL() { 
    THISURL="`head -n 1 $INFILE`"
    [ "$THISURL" = "__EMD__" ] && return 1;
    grep -v "$THISURL" $INFILE > tmp.$INFILE
    mv tmp.$INFILE $INFILE
}

doDEBUG
if [ $1 = "getlst.src1" ] ; then FLD=5; else if [ $1 = "getlst.src2" ]; then FLD=9; else echo "Unknown file: ${1}! Use known files or update the script!"; fi; fi
pids=""
INFILE=$1
doDEBUG
# Run five concurrent processes
for i in {1..10}; do
    fetchURL || break
    doDEBUG
        ( enqueue $THISURL ) &
    doDEBUG
        # store PID of process
        pids+=" $!"
    doDEBUG
done

# Wait for all processes to finish, will take max 14s
# as it waits in order of launch, not order of finishing
for p in $pids; do
        if wait $p; then
        NP=""
        for X in $pids do [ $X -eq $p ] || NP+=" $X"; 
        pids=$NP
        doDEBUG
        while [ `echo $pids | wc -l` -lt 10]; do 
            if [ `FETCHURL` ]; then 
                doDEBUG
                ( enqueue $THISURL   ) &
                doDEBUG
                pids+=" $!" ;
            else
                break;
            fi;
        done;
    else
        doDEBUG
        echo "Fetching $THISURL failed! Aborting Loop!"
        exit 1;
        fi;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found a couple of glitches in my code and once I fixed them it seems to be working okay. Sometimes you just have to get away for a few minutes.